# Log4j maven dependency won't log to console

Tags: java, maven, logging, console, log4j

this is my first try with Log4j, when I run the code I got the following error:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
```

Here is my code, syntax and logic seems right, should I configure/create any files?

```
package main;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;

public class Main {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            
            logger.info("START.");
            Service.readConfig();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: @JustAnotherDeveloper I haven't any configuration file...

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any configuration files, log4j is going with the default configuration, which is assigning the root logger to the `ERROR` [logging level](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Level.html). Configuring a level on a logger will cause logging events of that level and those that are **more specific** to pass through the filter. `INFO`, which is the level you are logging when you call `logger.info()` is **less specific** and thus it's not  getting logged. You need to configure the logger to log at least `INFO`, or log `ERROR` or `FATAL` using the corresponding methods. You can read how to configure the logger level in log4j's [documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/index.html).